# Sending balance to contract fails

Tags: transfer, fallback-function, receive, send

I'm playing ethernaut, the king of the hill level. I made a practice target contract and an attacking contract. I want to send value to the attacking contract (this works) then I want to send the balance of the attacking contract to the practice target contract (this fails). I'm able to send balance to the zero address, but not to this practice target, so I think the issue is with how I've written the practice target. I've read in other threads on here that it needs a payable fallback or receive function, but it fails regardless of having those. This is the practice target:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract practice {
    uint public amount;
    event paid(uint amount);
    event received(uint amount);
    receive() external payable {
        emit received(msg.value);
        amount += msg.value;
    }
    fallback() external payable {
        emit paid(msg.value);
        amount += msg.value;
    }
}
```

this is the attack contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract King {
    uint public amount;
    address public target;
  
    constructor() payable {
        amount += msg.value;
    }

    event attempt(uint amount, address sender);
    event fallbackCalled(uint amount, address sender);
    event valueAdded(uint amount, address sender);
    event successfulTransfer(uint amount);
    event failed(uint amount);

    function setTarget(address _target) public {
        target = _target;
    }

    function addValue() public payable {
        emit valueAdded(msg.value, msg.sender);
        amount += msg.value;
    }

    function sendBalance() public {
        emit attempt(address(this).balance, msg.sender);
        bool success = payable(target).send(address(this).balance);
        if (success) {
            emit successfulTransfer(address(this).balance);
            amount = 0;
        }
        if (!success) emit failed(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Not sure if it matters but I'm testing it on the rinkeby network via remix injected web3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is with `payable(target).send()`. This is because `send()` has a gas limit of 2,300, which is just about enough to log an event. But since the `receive()` function contains a state change operation, `send()` will fail due to gas overrun.

You could instead use `target.call{value: address(this).balance}("")` to send ETH to the target contract.

All the best with ethernaut!

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge, and so quickly. Your solution worked, have an awesome day!